# How to get data of an image after scale in fabricjs

Tags: javascript, scale, fabricjs

I apply a filter on my image where I modify each pixel. The issue is when I change the scale of an image, fabricjs give always the original image (before scale) as input of the filter. Then, I cannot modify each pixel of new data (after scale).

Does somebody know how to do that ? It'll be awesome, thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Doing this involves what you'd expect. There are no shortcuts or built-in features to do this. I've created a proof-of-concept [on this fork](https://github.com/semireg/fabric.js/commit/caf294a36483326edc8e9376a55ff48c4a7749ec). It's not perfect - caching is disabled. If you click through the link you'll find that this branch is forked from another [POC branch of mine](https://github.com/semireg/fabric.js/commit/b507d7266d4726611706f5fc363d46732cb2440f). I've tried to cleanup the code below. If I submit a PR back to the parent project I'll update this answer.

The changes mostly affect applyFilters function of image.class.js:

```
  applyFilters: function(filters) {

  filters = filters || this.filters || [];
  filters = filters.filter(function(filter) { return filter; });
  if (this.group) {
    this.set('dirty', true);
  }
  if (filters.length === 0) {
    this._element = this._originalElement;
    this._filterScalingX = 1;
    this._filterScalingY = 1;
    return this;
  }

  var imgElement = this._scaledEl || this._originalElement,
      sourceWidth = imgElement.naturalWidth || imgElement.width,
      sourceHeight = imgElement.naturalHeight || imgElement.height;

  if (!this._filteredEl || this._filteredEl === this._originalElement) {
    // if the element is the same we need to create a new element
    var canvasEl = fabric.util.createCanvasElement();
    canvasEl.width = sourceWidth;
    canvasEl.height = sourceHeight;
    this._element = canvasEl;
    this._filteredEl = canvasEl;
  }
  else {
    // clear the existing element to get new filter data
    this._element = this._filteredEl;
    this._filteredEl.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, sourceWidth, sourceHeight);
  }

  if (!fabric.filterBackend) {
    fabric.filterBackend = fabric.initFilterBackend();
  }

  fabric.filterBackend.applyFilters(filters, this._originalElement, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, this._element, this.cacheKey);

  if (this._originalElement.width !== this._element.width ||
    this._originalElement.height !== this._element.height) {
    this._filterScalingX = this._element.width / this._originalElement.width;
    this._filterScalingY = this._element.height / this._originalElement.height;
  }
  return this;
},
```